# In the upcoming Caruana, Carlsen final, who will play with the white pieces?

Tags: fide, world-championship, carlsen

In the upcoming Caruana, Carlsen final, who will play with the white pieces?

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 8):

Do you mean in the World Chess Championship 2018?

That will be a 12-game match, and not just a single game. The players will alternate colors, so they both will play 6 games with White.

Comment: Who is going to play White in the first game?

Comment: @A. N. Other Yes I think that's what the question was referring to.